# gsutil will not download files to my windows machine from powershell

Tags: google-cloud-storage

```
gsutil -m cp -R 'gs://[BUCKET]/' 'C:/Users/[USER]/[FOLDER]'
```

will display the following error

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('ab') or filename: u'C:\\Users\\[USER]\\[FOLDER]\\\\[BUCKET]\\[FILE].gstmp'
```

I've tried changing the '/'s to '//' to '\' and '\' with no results whatsoever

Comment: For a solution, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866242/2178980

Answer (score 3):

So, after hours trying to find out this was happening.. it happened that the filenames had a character that can't be used in filenames in windows.. hope this helps if anybody else runs into this error.